# Want to iterate a string that after each charater there will be a space in PHP

Tags: php, string

I want to iterate a string in the manner that after each character there should be a space and there will be new string(word) as per the main string character count.

For example

If I put the string "v40eb" as an input. Then Output be something like below.

```
   v 40eb
   v4 0eb
   v40 eb
   v40e b
```

OR

In Array form like below.

```
   [0]=>v 40eb[1]=>v4 0eb[2]=>v40 eb[3]=>v40e b
```

I am using PHP.

Thanks

Comment: Show us what you've tried, your best attempt (code) so we can help you on your way.

Comment: @jibsteroos I have no idea how to do it  I have a variable  $str="v40eb";  and want to generate the string or array like  v 40eb,v4 0eb,v40 eb,v40e b  OR [0]=>v 40eb[1]=>v4 0eb[2]=>v40 eb[3]=>v40e b

Comment: Kindly post some of your code/efforts then only we can help you.

Comment: Please `edit ` your post to add relevant code to the body of the post itself. Relevant info info should be embedded in the question itself, rather than relegated to comments alone. Thanks and welcome to SO.

Answer (score 1):

- Well, you can divide the process of putting a space into 2 parts.
- Get first part of the substring, append a space.
- Get second part of the substring and join them together.
- Use [`substr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to get a substring of a string.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$str = "v40eb";

$result = [];
$len = strlen($str);

for($i=0;$i<$len;++$i){
   $part1 = substr($str,0,$i+1);
   if($i < $len-1) $part1 .= " ";
   $part2 = substr($str,$i+1);
   $result[] =  $part1 . $part2;
}

print_r($result);
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/XGN0a

Answer (score 1):

You could simply loop over the char positions and use [`substr`](https://www.php.net/substr) to get the two parts for each:

```
$input = 'v40eb';

$combinations = [];
for ($charPos = 1, $charPosMax = strlen($input); $charPos < $charPosMax; $charPos++) {
  $combinations[] = substr($input, 0, $charPos) . ' ' . substr($input, $charPos);
}

print_r($combinations);
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/EeT1V**

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = 'v40eb';
for($i = 1; $i< strlen($input); $i++) {
    $array = str_split($input);
    array_splice($array, $i, 0, ' '); 
    $output[] = implode($array);
}
print_r($output);
```

Comment: While this code may work, is best to give a bit of context, or explanation of how/why this code solves the OP's question. High quality answers help pale future visitors learn, and are more likely to result in upvotes. It also keeps SO Q & A remain a high quality site.

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget to check the codec. You might use mb_-prefix to use the multibyte-functions.